# How to find the IPFS address of an NFT on SuperRare?

Tags: ipfs, nft

The link to an NFT on SuperRare, an Ethereum-based NFT platform, is shown below. How can I find the IPFS address of the `.mp4` file and view the video stand-alone?

https://superrare.co/artwork-v2/the-end-23896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SuperRare page you can see the history of the NFT, the first entry being the creation. You can view the transaction in Etherscan by clicking the link. This is the creation transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcbe836b09b0483cf552b5671ce1f6bf7cb6270cec4a65c8b53df96fc7c0a078f

From Etherscan you can see it's an ERC-721 token with an ID of 23896.

You can view the token contract on Etherscan, here:

https://etherscan.io/token/0xb932a70a57673d89f4acffbe830e8ed7f75fb9e0?a=23896

By clicking the "Contract" tab, and then "Read Contract", you can enter the contract ID in the `tokenURI` field to get the URI:

https://ipfs.pixura.io/ipfs/Qmareksn3LcJyBuLWV1tK75AfFBheTkMBP7R4EpFoaM8pr/metadata.json

Navigating to that link gives you the metadata:

```
{
    name: "The End",
    createdBy: "404.zero",
    yearCreated: "2019",
    description: "Procedurally generated landscapes. The sound is generated with vintage synthesizers Buchla 200 Series and EMS Synthi AKS.",
    image: "https://ipfs.pixura.io/ipfs/QmRHMeF5tTM6Qm1pGk6ogojVSp3ymUX917zmoBRriBrA4v/LiveAV_BrookMAIN_V8gameClip.9-V001.00_00_42_21.Still001.jpg",
    media: {
        uri: "https://ipfs.pixura.io/ipfs/QmexqvmMpkWW2t8BKaXpLjeLGYL1pZFHhAjjUsKYEXGNNk/LiveAV_BrookMAIN_V8gameClip.9-V001.mp4",
        dimensions: "1080x1350",
        size: "47620221",
        mimeType: "video/mp4"
    },
    tags: [
        "theend",
        "procedural",
        "generativeart",
        "surreal",
        "future"
    ]
}
```

And the URI for the media: https://ipfs.pixura.io/ipfs/QmexqvmMpkWW2t8BKaXpLjeLGYL1pZFHhAjjUsKYEXGNNk/LiveAV_BrookMAIN_V8gameClip.9-V001.mp4

Comment: Why is the .json file format used for writing NFT metadata?

Comment: A few reasons I can think of: a) many developers are already familiar with the syntax, b) it's an open standard format, c) it's already widely used in online data transfer and in defining schemas, d) it's human-readable. Basically it provides what is needed - it probably wasn't worth reinventing the wheel :-)

Comment: Thanks, why .json vs .txt explains it too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509942/why-json-and-not-txt

Comment: @user610620 - thanks for the link! :-)